# GPU fans not spinning on a headless ubuntu server 18.04

Tags: drivers, server, nvidia, graphics, fan

I got a PC from a friend of mine, which has an i5 and a GTX 1060 from Gigabyte. I installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 on the machine to use it as a server, however, the GPU fans are not spinning.

I've tried installing nvidia drivers and changing the fan speeds using nvidia-xconfig, but that resulted in errors because there is no display attached. What I've also tried is setting the fan speeds with pwm1 in hwmon.

Is there a way to fix this software-wise or is there a chance the GPU fans are just dead? Thanks in advance.

edit: the GPU had passive cooling enabled under low load (surprises me the temps climbed to low 60's.) I decided to remove the GPU, since I'm not using it.

Comment: the gpu fans are very likely dead. they are supposed to be controlled by the graphic card allone, in fact modern gpus even do dust cleaning backwards cycles on power-on so part of the logic controlling the fans is in the card. try with another os like windows and you'll see.

Comment: @tatsu they work, but apparently they have passive cooling enabled. since i'm not using the GPU, I decided to remove it. thanks for the help tho.

Comment: no problem. welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Do `gedit admin:///etc/X11/xorg.conf`

After that, go to the line that says `Option         "Coolbits" "4"` and ensure it says that. My issue was that it said 28 instead of 4.